# SQL Query Use of CASE inside Select

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, select, case

Hello I have a SQL Query:

```
select DateDiff(d,StartDate, EndDate) DaysEmployed from ClientDayActivity
```

I want this to become like this:

```
EmployDays = CASE WHEN NOT end_date IS NULL THEN
DATEDIFF(d,start_date, end_date) ELSE   
DATEDIFF(d,start_date, CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & Cstr(strEndDate) & "', 102)) END
```

I picked this query from old application and I have to use it according to my DB and application. I picked up
this query from asp code, they had a string of query. As well as I am not getting what is this: 
`'" & Cstr(strEndDate) & "'`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'" & Cstr(strEndDate) & "'` This looks like a dynamic SQL statement from VB.

strEndDate was the name of some variable that probably contained a date that was then converted to a string using `Cstr` and than added to SQL statement.

If you want to do something similar in a stored proc you're probably going to want

```
EmployDays = CASE WHEN NOT end_date IS NULL THEN
DATEDIFF(d,start_date, end_date) ELSE   
DATEDIFF(d,start_date, @end_date) END
```

where `@end_date` is a parameter. Alternatively you can use `GetDate()` which would use today's date which would make some sense given the case statement logic and the column alias

Here's a sample in a select

```
SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN NOT end_date IS NULL THEN
        DATEDIFF(d,start_date, end_date) 
     ELSE   
       DATEDIFF(d,start_date, @end_date) 
   END as EmployDays,
   some_other_field
FROM
       sometable
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As my SP has multiple columns in select statement, so this syntax is not valid there. It gives syntax error

Comment: Secondly, what does Cstr do? Is it same as GetDate in SQL?

Comment: I updated the answer to include a sample with a Select . [`Cstr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk841e9(v=vs.85).aspx) converts a value to a string.

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted. Please make me clear at two things: 1. In old application, he is not assigning value to `strEndDate` anywhere. 2. `CASE` can be used only at the Start of the query or anywhere else as well? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @asma. You can use a CASE statement anywhere you would use a column.  So it can be in any position in the SELECT and more exotically in other clauses (ON, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY) etc. I have no idea what it means that strEndDate was never set. That would make the value 1/1/1900, but then why use a variable? I would try and run the application or try and find out what's supposed to be there when there is no end_date in the database or ask your users.